# vector is holding single value instead of multiple values

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to c++, this question might be silly to you.

I am using [Network Optix](https://www.networkoptix.com/)  Video management service. Using their application I am building a plugin.

I am using below code snippet to create metadata object packet.

```
std::vector<IMetadataPacket*> DeviceAgent::cookSomeObjects()
{

    std::vector<IMetadataPacket*> result;

    auto objectMetadataPacket = makePtr<ObjectMetadataPacket>();
    objectMetadataPacket->setTimestampUs(m_lastVideoFrameTimestampUs);
    objectMetadataPacket->setDurationUs(0);

    auto j = json::parse(readBuffer);

    for (auto& context : j) {

       float a = context["x1"];
       float b = context["y1"];
       float c = context["height"];
       float d = context["width"];
       std::string label = context["label"];

       auto objectMetadata = makePtr<ObjectMetadata>();

       objectMetadata->setBoundingBox(Rect(a, b, c, d));

       objectMetadataPacket->addItem(objectMetadata.get());
      } 
    result.push_back(objectMetadataPacket.releasePtr());
    return result;
}
```

readBuffer is a response of API call. it contens looks like below.

> [{"height":0.10374343395233154,"label":"car","width":0.13737773895263672,"x1":0.4747169017791748,"y1":0.27557021379470825},{"height":0.1520291566848755,"label":"car","width":0.23306196182966232,"x1":0.0436464324593544,"y1":0.4737709164619446},{"height":0.05128565430641174,"label":"car","width":0.08260226249694824,"x1":0.5227476954460144,"y1":0.1012464314699173},{"height":0.2633265256881714,"label":"car","width":0.2628181278705597,"x1":0.26807519793510437,"y1":0.6712638735771179},{"height":0.1066703349351883,"label":"car","width":0.1351754069328308,"x1":0.3640907108783722,"y1":0.19261829555034637},{"height":0.13967299461364746,"label":"bike","width":0.09549647569656372,"x1":0.22761660814285278,"y1":0.5885671973228455},{"height":0.06679290533065796,"label":"car","width":0.07677030563354492,"x1":0.7689603567123413,"y1":0.15423545241355896},{"height":0.08153106272220612,"label":"car","width":0.09254050254821777,"x1":0.6379277110099792,"y1":0.19936798512935638},{"height":0.13518506288528442,"label":"car","width":0.11784732341766357,"x1":0.6905719637870789,"y1":0.34653833508491516}]

Basically the above code parses each object in J and create bouding boxed in objectMetadata pointer. objectMetadataPacket holds each objectMetadata pointer one by one.

When I print objectMetadata it returns 1 as I ecpected. But, When I print `objectMetadataPacket` 
it also returns 1 instead n number of objects in J. I think objectMetadataPacket is holding or replacing single value, instead of appending with previous values.

How to fix this? 
Any hint would be appreciable.

Comment: You call `push_back` exactly once, so why do you expect `result` to contain more than one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty simple, you need to move `push_back` so that it is inside your loop, not after your loop.

Something like this

```
std::vector<IMetadataPacket*> DeviceAgent::cookSomeObjects()
{

    auto j = json::parse(readBuffer);

    for (auto& context : j) {

       float a = context["x1"];
       float b = context["y1"];
       float c = context["height"];
       float d = context["width"];
       std::string label = context["label"];

       auto objectMetadata = makePtr<ObjectMetadata>();

       objectMetadata->setBoundingBox(Rect(a, b, c, d));

       auto objectMetadataPacket = makePtr<ObjectMetadataPacket>();
       objectMetadataPacket->setTimestampUs(m_lastVideoFrameTimestampUs);
       objectMetadataPacket->setDurationUs(0);
       objectMetadataPacket->addItem(objectMetadata.get());
       result.push_back(objectMetadataPacket.releasePtr());
      } 
    return result;
}
```

Obviously if you only push back one item to your vector then it's size is only going to be one.

Looking again at your code, I don't see a declaration for `result`. Where is it declared? Maybe that's the source of the confusion.

Comment: Please take a look at updated post to how result was declared. Sorry my bad.

Comment: do you have header file attached which has definition of ObjectMetadataPacket?

Comment: So is your question about the behaviour of `std::vector` or the behaviour of `ObjectMetadataPacket`. I'm afraid I only know anything about the first.

Answer (score 1):

Lets **suppose** result is a vector type. still you are pushing only last object to it. 
move this line

```
result.push_back(objectMetadataPacket.releasePtr());
```

inside for loop.

Don't forget to add header file which has definition of objectMetadataPacket.

Hope this will help you.